# Loading SVG by Uri and removing whitespace in Android

Tags: android, drawable, android-glide, android-vectordrawable, sag

The image url is:
https://static-qa-singlecare.s3.amazonaws.com/content/images/pharmacy/logo-color-riteaid.svg

If download we can see it contains a lot of whitespace top and bottom.

I am using this lib to load:
https://github.com/corouteam/GlideToVectorYou

Looks like its outdated and no more supported.

I need to load image inside container so it contains no whitespace top and bottom.

Current code:

```
RequestBuilder<PictureDrawable> requestBuilder;
requestBuilder= GlideToVectorYou
                .init()
                .with(activity)
                .getRequestBuilder();
requestBuilder
                .load(uri)
                .into(pharmacyImage);
```

Comment: Could you please include your Android code of how you are adding the image to your activity layout.

Comment: @se22as added my code